# Getting "Unexected null value" while using createSession on flutter

Tags: flutter, connectycube

I'm trying to implement a login screen using the examples provided by connectycube, the CubeUser object provided as a parameter to the function createSession contains both the login and password fields but i always get the exception both on android or web. By debugging, I ascertained that the CubeUser object is correctly defined

I also tried to add more field to the CubeUser object (fullname, email) but the error persists.

Comment: please provide more info about your issue. please add logs that contain the request and the response